# showing database value with an image using JSP

Tags: javascript, html, database, image, jsp

I have created a simple site that reads a database table and displays it in a html table in the browser.
I have a button that allows for the table to be altered, saved & then automatically forwarded to the homepage with the updated table.
I also have a select button with which the user can select that particular row and it updates a column in the table.

My problem is that I need a way to show which row has been selected.
I prefer to have a column in the HTML table that shows an image as to which one is selected.

Here is my homepage where the database table is being displayed.
In the left column of the html is where I would like to add an image if that row is selected.

I have tried several things like using javascript and just can't wrap my head around it?
Can I get some help?

```html
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page import="java.io.*, java.util.*, java.sql.*"%>
<%@page import="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleConnection" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script language="javascript">

    function editRecord(id) {
        var f=document.form;
        f.method="post";
        f.action='edit.jsp?id='+id;
        f.submit();
    }

    function selectRecord(id, btn, i) {
        var f=document.form;
        f.method="post";
        f.action='select.jsp?id='+id;
        f.submit();

        if(!btn.style) {
            alert("not supported");
            return;
        } else{
            btn.style.background = "red";
            return;
        }
    }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <br><br>
    <form method="post" name="form">
        <table id="data" border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>Selected</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th>Contact No</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Select</th>
        </tr>
        <%
        int sumcount=0;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        Connection con = null;
        Statement st = null;

        try {
            DriverManager.registerDriver (new oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver());
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE", "username", "password");

            st = con.createStatement();
            rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM employee");
        %> 
        <%
            while(rs.next()) {
        %>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><%=rs.getString(2)%></td>
                <td><%=rs.getString(3)%></td>
                <td><%=rs.getString(4)%></td>
                <td><%=rs.getString(5)%></td>
                <td><input type="button" name="edit" value="Edit" style="background-color:#49743D;font-weight:bold;color:#ffffff;" onclick="editRecord(<%=rs.getString(1)%>);" /></td>
                <td><input type="button" name="select" value="Select" style="background-color:#49743D;font-weight:bold;color:#ffffff;" onclick="selectRecord(<%=rs.getString(1)%>, this);" /></td>
            </tr>
        <%
            }
        %>
        <%
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        %>

        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not sure about JSP, but I'd use some JQuery and ajax to get an identifier for the selected row and alter it's css to indicate selection state. The ajax should pass the identifier for the selected row to some server script or whatever so that it can be manipulated on the database end

Comment: Hi Josh, are you still trying to figure this out or were you able to come up with a solution?  I'd love to hear about it if you did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 <script language="javascript">

    function editRecord(id) {
        var f=document.form;
        f.method="post";
        f.action='edit.jsp?id='+id;
        f.submit();
    }

    function selectRecord(id, btn, i) {
     //Here goes the code to display image
        var images = document.getElementsByName("selectImg");
        for(var i=0;i<images.length;i++){
            if(images[i].id!="img_"+id)
               images[i].style.display="None";
            else
               images[i].style.display="Block";
         }
     //End
        var f=document.form;
        f.method="post";
        f.action='select.jsp?id='+id;
        f.submit();

        if(!btn.style) {
            alert("not supported");
            return;
        } else{
            btn.style.background = "red";
            return;
        }
    }
    </script>
```

You need to put a hidden div with image in first column.

```
    <%
        while(rs.next()) {
    %>
        <tr>
            <td><div name="selectImg" id="img_<%=rs.getString(1)%>">
                <img src="path_to_image"></div></td>
            <td><%=rs.getString(2)%></td>
            <td><%=rs.getString(3)%></td>
            <td><%=rs.getString(4)%></td>
            <td><%=rs.getString(5)%></td>
            <td><input type="button" name="edit" value="Edit" style="background-color:#49743D;font-weight:bold;color:#ffffff;" onclick="editRecord(<%=rs.getString(1)%>);" /></td>
            <td><input type="button" name="select" value="Select" style="background-color:#49743D;font-weight:bold;color:#ffffff;" onclick="selectRecord(<%=rs.getString(1)%>, this);" /></td>
```